# How to dynamically get the values from Object Type and implement in Expansion panel Angular material?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

**Scenario**:

Displaying the expansion panel name and content Dynamically using Angular material expansion panel using JSON.

**Issue**:

I able to place the Panel name  Dynamically but for the content, I need to check the JSON in that I have a **type**  key so based on type I need to push that particular functionality that particular div.

**JSON**:

```
[{
          module: "Person Details",
          type: 'table',
          moduleData: [
            {
              "firstName":"MaxRunner",
              "ID":"12345",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          module: "Current Location",
          type: 'horizontal-stepper',
          CurrentData: [
            {
              "step":1,
              "description":"Philips",
              "status":true
            },
            {
              "step":2,
              "description":"Philips",
              "status":true
            },
            {
              "step":3,
              "description":"Philips",
              "status":false
            }
          ]
        }
      ];
```

here based on **type** key and I am pushing the **moduledata** key to the div present what I did was like
I manually gave the key names but suppose in future in future if I have objects then I manually cannot set each name in div so is there any dynamically way to do this?

what I did

```
<div  *ngIf="module.type==='table'">
        <div *ngFor="let moduleKey of getKeys(module.moduleData[0])">
            <div > {{ moduleKey }} </div>
            <div> {{module.moduleData[0][moduleKey]}} </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div style="border-bottom:0;" *ngIf="module.type==='horizontal-stepper'">   
    <div [ngClass]="'col-xs-3' + getStatusClass(step, index, module.CurrentData)" *ngFor="let step of module.CurrentData; let index = index">
      <div><div class="progress-bar"></div></div>
      <div >{{step.step}}</div>
      <div class="bs-wizard-info text-center" *ngIf="isActive(step.status, index, module.CurrentData)">{{step.description}}</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

IN the code currently, I am implementing a manual way like giving the key name "**module.CurrentData**"

here I don't want to give name manually  like "**getStatusClass(step, index, module.CurrentData)**"

Here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/expansion-panel-sawju6).

Comment: I didn't quite get your requirement. If you don't want to give name manually then you should have some configuration for that. Or at least some mapping

Comment: @yurzui right now i am mentioning name like below getStatusClass(step, index, module.CurrentData)  directly i mentining key names but  how can i map it in dynamic way with out mentioning it in hardcoded way

Comment: what you are doing is converting your model into a viewModel (i.e. the model the Template needs to display data correct). however you are doing this in the template. is there any reason, you aren't doing this conversation outside the template? i.e. when you get the data from your source, to the validation for things such as isActive. this would greatly simply your HTML and avoid the HTML having to apply business logic.

Comment: No Specific Reason for doing this is templates @Edward  is there any other way ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the updated (generic) version: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/expansion-panel-9pfmtp?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

- I have Updated the data to be more generic by adding `data` property instead of different property name for different types.

**Here is the data look like now:**

```
this.data = [{
          module: "Person Details",
          type: 'table',
          data: [
            {
              "firstName":"MaxRunner",
              "ID":"12345",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          module: "Current Location",
          type: 'horizontal-stepper',
          data: [
            {
              "step":1,
              "description":"Philips",
              "status":true
            },
            {
              "step":2,
              "description":"Philips",
              "status":true
            },
            {
              "step":3,
              "description":"Philips",
              "status":false
            }
          ]
        }
      ];
```

- I have updated the template code and now you only need to pass data instead of different names for different types.

```html
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let module of data">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            {{module.module}}
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>

        <div  *ngIf="module.type==='table'">
            <div *ngFor="let moduleKey of getKeys(module.data[0])">
                <div > {{ moduleKey }} </div>
                <div> {{module.data[0][moduleKey]}} </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="border-bottom:0;" *ngIf="module.type==='horizontal-stepper'">   
            <div [ngClass]="'col-xs-3' + getStatusClass(step, index, module.data)" *ngFor="let step of module.data; let index = index">
              <div><div class="progress-bar"></div></div>
              <div >{{step.step}}</div>
              <div class="bs-wizard-info text-center" *ngIf="isActive(step.status, index, module.data)">{{step.description}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </mat-expansion-panel>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this will help you. But in angular, there is a way to iterate over the key-value pairs using [keyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe#examples). With this, you will get the key without hardcoding. For example,

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let module of modules">
  <div *ngFor="let moduleKey of module|keyvalue">
   <!--you can have dynamic key such as moduledata|currentData etc-->
</div>
</ng-container>
```